# Using Google Map to show location when called from another app

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create an app with a list of all nearby hotels that I include

I was thinking if it was possible that, as I click on button with a hotel name, Google Maps would pop up and give the location of that hotel from the current position of the user...
More specifically, what I want to know is, as I click on hotel tab (of my to-be-made app), I want Google Maps to open and show the hotel as well as the user on Google Map.

Comment: Search this site, or use google. I am sure that there are plenty of information to help you with this.

Comment: Read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Comment: You can [integrate Google Maps into this fictional app](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start). No need to open the Maps app itself.

Comment: thats a great advice you just gave me sir..thing is, as a beginner i needed a starting point and u just gave me one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches for the solution to your query.

1.) You show the route through google map on your own app. Follow the below links for better explanation:

[Google Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

[Google Directions from scratch](http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/)

2.) Or you can open google maps directly from the your app and let all routing headache handled by google maps. You can do this using Intent as:

```
String uri = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + ""; 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

[Opening Maps from Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents)

Hopefully this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: didnt expect answer so fast..thanks for the kind response..

Comment: hope the answers helps you...